# SQL Server freetexttable special characters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, freetexttable

When I use `FreeTextTable` in SQL Server and pass search key with a special character like hyphen, it looks for all results matching for keyword `partone` or keyword `parttwo`.

How can I restrict it doing that and search for `partone=parttwo` as one word? if that is not possible what are my alternates, I am dealing with large number of rows.

```
select * 
from freetexttable(dbo.TableName, (FieldOne, FieldTwo), 'partone-parttwo')
```